# Swift 4: NSFilenamesPboardType not available. What to use instead for registerForDraggedTypes?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, swift4

After migrating to Swift4 the following code raise compile error:

```
public final class MediaItemView: NSView {

   public override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
      super.init(frame: frameRect)

      // error: 'NSFilenamesPboardType' is unavailable in Swift:
      // use 'NSPasteboard.writeObjects(_:)' with file URLs
      let draggedTypes: [NSPasteboard.PasteboardType] = [NSFilenamesPboardType]
      registerForDraggedTypes(draggedTypes)
   }
}
```

What is a replacement for `NSFilenamesPboardType` in Swift4? How to register drag type of `file name` (in my case mp3, wav, aiff, ... files) in Swift4?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

I've solved backwards compatibility with this extension:

```
extension NSPasteboard.PasteboardType {

    static let backwardsCompatibleFileURL: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType = {

            if #available(OSX 10.13, *) {
                return NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.fileURL
            } else {
                return NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(kUTTypeFileURL as String)
            }

    } ()

}
```

Which means you can use `NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.backwardsCompatibleFileURL`

Comment: Hm. It did not work well for me, I was unable to get to proper dragged filenames; got something like `Optional(file:///.file/id=6571367.2747208)` instead. Hack-ish @slboat solution worked better.

Comment: @TomekCejner I get the same kind of strings (probably related to sandboxing), but they work fine once you turn them into a URL with `URL(string:)`. The `absoluteString` method then gives you the normal filesystem path.

Answer (score 13):

i use this as the solution

```
    //Temp solution for this
    let NSFilenamesPboardTypeTemp = NSPasteboard.PasteboardType("NSFilenamesPboardType")

    self.zipView.registerForDraggedTypes([NSFilenamesPboardTypeTemp])
```

it's seem a bug from apple,them marked the api as work in 10.13 only.

[image: i fire a bug to apple:)]

Comment: I also did this. Seems dangerous but is working for me. #yolo

Comment: Registering with this type seems to work in 10.13, but reading from the paste board fails with "'NSFilenamesPboardType' is not a valid UTI string.  Cannot read data for an invalid UTI." Mark Bridges answer using `kUTTypeFileURL` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

I like the creative workarounds presented here for the deprecated variable `NSFilenamesPboardType`. After looking into this question, a way to move forward with an *equivalent non-deprecated approach* is to use `readObjects(forClasses:options:)`. This would also be safer WRT  being able to run on future macOSes. It would be implemented like the following example, tested with Swift 4.1, based on having an `NSView` registered in a storyboard.

```
override func awakeFromNib()
{
    registerForDraggedTypes([.fileURL])
}

override func draggingEnded(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo)
{
    sender
        .draggingPasteboard()
        .readObjects(forClasses: [NSURL.self],
                     options: nil)?
        .forEach
        {
            // Do something with the file paths.
            if let url = $0 as? URL { print(url.path) }
        }
}
```

Since the class array parameter for `readObjects` is of type `[AnyClass]` that is the reason for the use of `NSURL` instead of `URL`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works in Swift 5.x. It is the only solution I've found so far that works with multiple files being dropped.

Answer (score 4):

I'm also running into the same issue and my solution is creating a custom `NSPasteboard.PasteboardType` with `kUTTypeURL`. I'm not sure if this is the most proper way (and I suppose not), but it works at least for temporal workaround.

```
    let draggedType = NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(kUTTypeURL as String)
    self.tableView?.registerForDraggedTypes([draggedType])
```

Furthermore, the new `NSPasteboard.PasteboardType` has `.fileNameType(forPathExtension: "foo")` method. You should give a try. However somehow, it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: As workaround there is also possible to do like this: `NSPasteboard.PasteboardType("NSFilenamesPboardType")`

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of [Mark Bridges' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46514780/4118208) and [slboat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46254276/4118208), this is the solution I've come up with:

```
extension NSPasteboard.PasteboardType {

    /// The name of a file or directory
    static let fileName: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType = {
        return NSPasteboard.PasteboardType("NSFilenamesPboardType")
    }()
}
```

This works as expected in my testing.

Answer (score 1):

***Swift 5***

```
//MARK:- Managing a Dragging Session After an Image Is Released

    override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        let fetched = sender.draggingPasteboard.readObjects(forClasses:  [NSURL.self], options: nil)?
            .map({ (argv) -> String? in
                guard let url = argv as? URL else{
                    return nil
                }
                return url.path
            }).compactMap({$0})

        guard let result = fetched else{
            return false
        }
        // handle the result
        print(result)
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift4, Swift5**:

Well part temporary workaround but working for Swift4/5:

```
var chromeType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType { return NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.init(rawValue: "org.chromium.drag-dummy-type") }
var finderNode: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType { return NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.init(rawValue: "com.apple.finder.node") }
var fileURLs: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType { return NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.init(rawValue: "NSFilenamesPboardType") }
var webarchive: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType { return NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.init(rawValue: "com.apple.webarchive") }
```

then aggregate as

```
var acceptableTypes: Set<NSPasteboard.PasteboardType> { return [.URL, .fileURL, .pdf, .png, .rtf, .rtfd, .tiff, finderNode, webarchive] }
```

then use in view did load method:

```
//  Intercept drags
registerForDraggedTypes(Array(acceptableTypes))
```