# Xcode Cocoa - Drag Drop from NSTableView to Finder

Tags: c#, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xamarin

I want my MacOS App to be able to Drag a item from NSTableView to an other Application like Logic Pro X, Finder, etc.
The items in this TableViews are classes I created which are representing Files on my HD.

```
public class AudioFile
{
    #region Computed Propoperties
    public string Filename { get; set; } = "";
    public string Filepath { get; set; } = "";
    #endregion

    public AudioFile()
    {
    }

    public AudioFile(string filename, string filepath)
    {
        this.Filename = filename;
        this.Filepath = filepath;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't find a solution for Swift or Objective-C which I could translate to C# (Xamarin). Does anyone know one or has some code that could help here?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I know nothing about C#, but you asked for a solution in Swift or Objective-C. That I can help with! The below is Swift 4.

First of all, make sure your `ViewController` is the table view's data source:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource
```

You will also need to make that connection either in code or in IB.

You then need to set your table view as a dragging source. Choose the operation you want, usually either `.move` or `.copy`:

```
tableView.setDraggingSourceOperationMask(.move, forLocal: false)
```

This example assumes that you're using an ArrayController to manage the content of the tableView. You really should be, it makes a host of things easier. Also, this example is for dragging multiple files. (It will work for a single file, but there are other approaches if you only ever want to drag one.)

In your ViewController class, implement this method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, writeRowsWith rowIndexes: IndexSet, to pboard: NSPasteboard) -> Bool {
    var filePaths = [String]()

    // Swift 4 hack--the FilenamesPboardType is missing
    let NSFilenamesPboardTypeTemp = NSPasteboard.PasteboardType("NSFilenamesPboardType")
    pboard.addTypes([NSFilenamesPboardTypeTemp], owner: nil)

    if let audioFiles = audioFilesArrayController.arrangedObjects as? [AudioFile] {
        for i in rowIndexes {
            filePaths.append(audioFiles[i].Filepath)
        }
    }

    pboard.setPropertyList(filePaths, forType: NSFilenamesPboardTypeTemp)

    return true
}
```

You can learn more about the `NSFilenamesPboardTypeTemp` hack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46254276/1749551).

And that's it! Recompile and you should be able to move one or more of your files by dragging them to a Finder window. Simple. :-)