# Swift 4+: Issues copying a String to Clipboard using NSPasteboard

Tags: swift, clipboard, nspasteboard, pasteboard

I had this all working in Swift 3 and earlier but with Swift 4 no matter what variation I use this code will instead output text as a URL.  If I put in "This is my sample text" the output after pasting the clipboard will be "This%20is%20my%20sample%20text". I have tried KuTTypeFileURL but that doesn't appear to make any difference either.  What am I missing here?  I have seen posts and discussions about how Apple is changing Pboards and other issues with sandboxing but I can't seem to figure this out at all.

original code what was working in swift 3 and earlier

```
private func copyToClipBoard(textToCopy: String) {
    let pasteBoard = NSPasteboard.general()
    pasteBoard.clearContents()
    pasteBoard.setString(textToCopy, forType: NSStringPboardType)

}
```

This gives an error of
    'NSStringPboardType' is unavailable in Swift: use 'PasteboardType.string'

After searching online I came across these posts that describe the same issue and the workaround was to use the kuTTypeUrl as String

Found here stackoverflow.com/questions/44537356/… and here forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79144

When I try it this way it simply outputs as a URL when I just need a String.

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: NSTextField!

@IBAction func nameCopy(_ sender: Any) {
    copyToClipBoard(textToCopy: nameTextField.stringValue)
}


let NSStringPboardType = NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(kUTTypeURL as String)

private func copyToClipBoard(textToCopy: String) {
    let pasteBoard = NSPasteboard.general
    pasteBoard.clearContents()
    pasteBoard.setString(textToCopy, forType: NSStringPboardType)
}
```

Comment: If you don't want the string treated like a URL why are you setting the type as `kUTTypeURL`? Please put enough code in your question to fully demonstrate your issue showing how you want to set the string and how you read the string.

Comment: I updated the post with more information to explain why I am using kUTTypeURL.  It was something I had found as a workaround when looking for a solution online.  Sorry if I didn't provide enough information originally.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are pasting an URL because you created a `PasteboardType` *kUTType**URL***.

The solution is much simpler, there is a predefined `string` type

```
private func copyToClipBoard(textToCopy: String) {
    let pasteBoard = NSPasteboard.general
    pasteBoard.clearContents()
    pasteBoard.setString(textToCopy, forType: .string)

}
```

The note in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboard.pasteboardtype/1527185-string)

> Apps that adopt App Sandbox cannot access files identified using the string pasteboard type. Instead, use an NSURL object, a bookmark, or a filename pasteboard type.

is related to **files** (aka string paths), not to regular strings

Comment: I originally had it coded this way in Swift 3 and earlier but now in Swift 4 I get an error "'NSStringPboardType' is unavailable in Swift: use 'PasteboardType.string'". After doing some digging online the workaround was to use the kUTTypeUrl.  Found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537356/swift-4-nsfilenamespboardtype-not-available-what-to-use-instead-for-registerfo and here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79144

Comment: How can I copy font with font style?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into a similar issue. My code looked like this:

```
NSPasteboard.general.setString("Hello World", forType: .string)
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work. But I figured there is a bug that if you don't store the `NSPasteboard.general` into a variable, the object created as part of the `general` computed property gets deinitialized before the `setString` change is propagated to the system.

So if you tried doing this in one line like me, just split it up to two instead, which worked for me:

```
let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
pasteboard.setString("Hello World", forType: .string)
```

I reported this bug via Feedback Assistant to Apple (FB9988062).

**UPDATE:**
Apple answered my bug report, stating that you need to call [`declareTypes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboard/1533561-declaretypes) before setting a value, like so:

```
NSPasteboard.general.declareTypes([.string], owner: nil)
```

Comment: you need to put `NSPasteboard.general.clearContents()` on the line before `NSPasteboard.general.setString("Hello World", forType: .string)`

Comment: @yes I just updated my answer with Apples official answer to my bug report. Can you elaborate why you would need to `clearContents()` first? Do you have a link to the documentation, for example?

Comment: `clearContents()`: "Clears the existing contents of the pasteboard, preparing it for new contents. This is the first step in providing data on the pasteboard." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboard/1533599-clearcontents?language=swift `declareTypes(_:owner:)`: "This method is the equivalent of invoking clearContents(), implicitly writing the first pasteboard item, and then calling addTypes(_:owner:) to promise types for the first pasteboard item." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboard/1533561-declaretypes?language=swift thats all i know